# SQL JOIN two JSON columns, by two related ids

Tags: sql, json, database, join, mariadb

I have two related JSON columns referring to multiple tables.

I need to match every resulting permutation.

#### Take:

**`writers`**:

```
| id | name | supervising (JSON)  | projects (JSON)   |
|:-- |:-----| :-------------------| :-----------------|
| 1  | John | ["3","4","5","6"]   | null              |
| 2  | Bill | ["7","8","9","10"]  | null              |
| 3  | Andy | null                | ["1","2"]         |
| 4  | Hank | null                | ["3","4","5"]     |
| 5  | Alex | null                | ["6","7","8"]     |
| 6  | Joe  | null                | ["9","10"]        |
| 7  | Ken  | null                | ["11","12","13"]  |
| 8  | Zach | null                | ["14","15","16"]  |
| 9  | Walt | null                | ["17","18"]       |
| 10 | Mike | null                | ["19","20","21"]  |
```

- `writers.supervising` is a JSON object referring to `writers.id`

  - John supervises Andy, Hank, Alex, and Joe
  - Bill supervises Ken, Zach, Walt, and Mike
- `writers.projects` is a JSON object referring to `projects.id`

  - Andy handles Boston and Chicago
  - Hank handles Cisco, Seattle, and North
  - et cetera

...John and Bill don't write; they supervise writers listed by `writers.id` in `writers.supervising` JSON.

The `writers` have `papers` they write...

**`projects`**:

```
| id | title    |
|:-- |:---------|
| 1  | Boston   |
| 2  | Chicago  |
| 3  | Cisco    |
| 4  | Seattle  |
| 5  | North    |
| 6  | West     |
| 7  | Miami    |
| 8  | York     |
| 9  | Tainan   |
| 10 | Seoul    |
| 11 | South    |
| 12 | Tokyo    |
| 13 | Carlisle |
| 14 | Fugging  |
| 15 | Turkey   |
| 16 | Paris    |
| 17 | Midguard |
| 18 | Fugging  |
| 19 | Madrid   |
| 20 | Salvador |
| 21 | Everett  |
```

I need to work with the supervisors and the papers:

1. Get a list of all `projects.id` by writers under John's supervision.
2. Check and see if:

- John (`writers.id`=1) is supervising the "Carlisle" (`projects.id`=13) project (0 rows)
- Bill (`writers.id`=2) is supervising the "Carlisle" (`projects.id`=13) project (1 row)

#### What I need:

I need something like...

1. Get a list of all `projects.id` by writers under John's supervision (`writers.id`=1).

```sql
SELECT p.id, p.title FROM projects p
JOIN writers w
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(writer s ON s.supervising
  JSON_CONTAINS(w.projects)
)
AND s.id = '1';
```

Desired result:

```
| 1  | Boston   |
| 2  | Chicago  |
| 3  | Cisco    |
| 4  | Seattle  |
| 5  | North    |
| 6  | West     |
| 7  | Miami    |
| 8  | York     |
| 9  | Tainan   |
| 10 | Seoul    |
```

2. Check if John (`id` 1) supervises Carlisle (`id` 13)

```sql
SELECT id FROM projects p
WHERE writer s JSON_CONTAINS(writer w ON s.supervising
  JSON_CONTAINS("13" ON p.id)
)
AND s.id = '1';
```

Desired result: `0 rows`

I don't think either is right. But, I know that I'm looking through permutations of two JSON objects.

Comment: Was the intent a [Markdown table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support)? This is used as an example in [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418550/when-to-use-code-formatted-tables-and-so-formatted-tables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I understand you problem correct, the result should be:

| supervisor | writer | project | p_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Andy | Boston | 1 |
| John | Andy | Chicago | 2 |
| John | Hank | Cisco | 3 |
| John | Alex | Miami | 7 |
| John | Hank | North | 5 |
| John | Hank | Seattle | 4 |
| John | Joe | Seoul | 10 |
| John | Joe | Tainan | 9 |
| John | Alex | West | 6 |
| John | Alex | York | 8 |

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT 0 AS x
   UNION ALL
   SELECT x+1 FROM cte ),
tbl_writers AS (
SELECT
   id,
   name,
   -- cte.x,
   JSON_VALUE(projects,CONCAT('$[',cte.x,']')) AS project
FROM writers
CROSS JOIN cte
WHERE JSON_VALUE(projects,CONCAT('$[',cte.x,']')) IS NOT NULL
),
tbl_supervisors AS (
SELECT
   id,
   name,
   -- cte.x,
   JSON_VALUE(supervising,CONCAT('$[',cte.x,']')) AS writer
FROM writers
CROSS JOIN cte
WHERE JSON_VALUE(supervising,CONCAT('$[',cte.x,']')) IS NOT NULL
)
-- SELECT * FROM tbl_supervisors;
-- SELECT * FROM tbl_writers;
SELECT
   s.name  AS supervisor,
   w.name  AS writer,
   p.title AS project,
   p.id    AS p_id
FROM tbl_supervisors s
LEFT JOIN tbl_writers w ON w.id = s.writer
INNER JOIN projects p ON p.id = w.project
-- WHERE s.name = 'Bill' -- For Bill by name
-- WHERE s.id = '2'      -- For Bill by id
-- WHERE s.name = 'John' -- For John by name
WHERE s.id = '1'         -- For John by id
ORDER BY project;        -- By project alphabetical
-- ORDER BY p_id;        -- Example ORDER BY option from out AS col
```

See: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=016fe5724f2deb57bc8f2e017868dfb4)

With the [common table expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression) (CTEs) I am first creating two tables, (`tbl_writers`) and (`tbl_supervisors`).  SQL works better on tables than on JSON-formatted data, because there wasn’t any JSON when SQL was born.